# BufferedReader Closes at the Beginning of a For-Loop in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

I am using BufferedReader to take in multiple inputs inside of a for a loop; however, when the first input comes in during the first time through, it throws the error

> java.io.Exception: Stream closed

Despite the fact that I don't close it until after the for loop ends. The code is below:

```
        BufferedReader menu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (int i = 0; players.length > i; i++) {
            System.out.println("Choose the " + i + " player");
            System.out.println("1. New Player");
            System.out.println("2. Old Player");
            int choice2 = Integer.parseInt(menu.readLine());
            System.out.println("Which team are you on?");
            int playersTeam = Integer.parseInt(menu.readLine());
            Person player = new Person();
            if (choice2 == 1) {
                player.squadFilling();
                player.playerNaming();
            } else if (choice2 == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        menu.close();
```

What is causing the crash, and how can I fix it? Thanks for your time!

Stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:181)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
    at Main.main(Main.java:409)
```

Comment: Is the error produced after the first iteration of the for-loop or on the first iteration after this block of code has been called once already?

Comment: The first iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: Is it possible that System.in has already been closed in another block of code prior to this call? When you close a Reader that uses System.in as the InputStream, that InputStream gets closed as well. This would mean you cannot use System.in again until it's instantiated again.

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't opening a new ```System.in``` open a new InputStream?

Comment: The System#in is assigned once on `System#initializeSystemClass`. The only time it's ever assigned a value is by System#setIn which you would have to call yourself.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I removed all the instances of BufferedReaders closing, and the for-loop worked for the first iteration and crashed on the second time through.

Comment: You'll likely have to try and solve that yourself and if you cannot solve it, ask another question.

Comment: That is what this question is....

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Posted the stacktrace

Comment: How are you supplying the input to this program when it runs? Manually typing? Piping input in from another program? Are there control characters in the input (ctrl-Z, ctrl-D)?

Comment: @FrasherGray - It's not this code (which you posted) which is causing this. I suspect some other part of your program is closing `System.in`. If you have removed `close()` statements from every place in your program, there may be a chance that you have used `System.in` inside some try-with-resources code which is closing `System.in`.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash, I checked through some code, and found something being closed in something I copypasted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FrasherGray - You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed some `.close()` commands placed elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try moving `menu.close();` to a different method called at the end. As well move the `BufferedReader menu` to a higher visibility out of the method and just use `menu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` in method.

```
BufferedReader menu;
void method(){
    menu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int i = 0; players.length > i; i++) {
        System.out.println("Choose the " + i + " player");
        System.out.println("1. New Player");
        System.out.println("2. Old Player");
        int choice2 = Integer.parseInt(menu.readLine());
        System.out.println("Which team are you on?");
        int playersTeam = Integer.parseInt(menu.readLine());
        Person player = new Person();
        if (choice2 == 1) {
            player.squadFilling();
            player.playerNaming();
        } else if (choice2 == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    cleanup();
}
```

This allows us to create a method cleanup().

```
private void cleanup(){
    menu.close();
}
```

The reason I think this might help is I believe menu.close() is being called while the writer is still finishing up from it's last loop. I think adding cleanup() as a separate method will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, its not throwing any Exception(trying same code). Its working fine.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

    BufferedReader menu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int i = 0; 2 > i; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Choose the " + i + " player");
                    System.out.println("1. New Player");
                    System.out.println("2. Old Player");
                    int choice2 = Integer.parseInt(menu.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Which team are you on?");
                    int playersTeam = Integer.parseInt(menu.readLine());
                    if (choice2 == 1) {
                        continue;
                    } else if (choice2 == 2) {
                        break;
                    }
                    
    }
    menu.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: huh. That isn't really an answer though

Comment: Which line is at Main.java:409 ?